# Web Essentials 2012, skip minifying sections

Tags: web-essentials

Is there any way to skip sections of the js when using the minifier in Web Essentials?

I have some script already minified in there, and for some reason it gets corrupt when minified again. Would be awesome if some comment format or what not could make it not minify parts of the document.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug in the minifier. While this won't help you immediately, if you could make a simple test case that can reliably reproduce the error then you could help everyone by reporting it to the author of the minifier and helping them to get this bug fixed for the next version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude individual files from minification in the current version 1.9.2 of Web Essentials, but it's on the backlog